# Unable to get Stylesheets and Javascript in visual studio code

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-code

I have created an test project in Visual Studio Code.
I have included a home.html in index.jade

**index.jade**

`include home.html`

And in home.html I'm just getting link href for bootstrap theme and bootstrap stylesheet.

**home.html**

```
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="../public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../public/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Now here is the problem, whenever I'm running my code im getting below error

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgitI.jpg)

```
GET /public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 404 67.491 ms - 1155

GET /public/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css 404 66.960 ms - 1155

GET /public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 404 37.134 ms - 1155
```

Here is My Folder Structure

[Folder Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlFAf.jpg)

Am I Doing Something Wrong??

Comment: try `/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css` without the dots

Comment: I Got It.

I just removed ../public

    <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css"rel="stylesheet">

It's working fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

I Got It.

I just removed ../public

```
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css"rel="stylesheet">
```

It's working fine now :)